# Can maven plugin be included and used as a dependency?

Tags: maven

Is it possible to use a maven plugin as a dependency within the dependencies element rather than within the plugins element? Is the only way to use a plugin to include it in the plugins element?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the use case where and why you want to do that?

Comment: A plugin is a JAR, so you can use it as a normal dependency, if you need to use it like a library. But I guess most of the plugins are not always organized (visibility, extensibility) to be used as a library.